# About WebAuthn(FIDO)

Tags: javascript, webauthn, fido

I was testing out WebAuthn **in front side**(this means **no backend thingy, like challenge, id, etc.**)

1. **Why does icon matter?**

When I first tried, I could only auth with a security key. But when I added an icon: undefined to publickey.user.icon, I could auth with Windows Hello. And, even if I insert a REAL icon link, it didn't show up. Windows 10 Edu, the latest version

2. **How can I implement it?**

I've found that I could use **res(navigator.credentials....).response.attestationObject**. Is this the right way to use WebAuthn?

3. **About physical security key**

Let's say I've got a security key USB with fingerprint support. Then I put my fingerprint then register with WebAuthn. Then my friend comes in, and he does the registration with his fingerprint. Then would the key(.response.attestationObject) **be the same together** because it's the **same physical fingerprint** or **be different** because **it's different fingerprints**?

Answer (score 2):

[Partial anwser here, I will be happy to see other answers from community members]

1. The `icon` parameter has been removed from the new version of the specification.

- Webauthn-1: https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-1/#dictionary-pkcredentialentity
- Webauthn-2: https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#dictionary-pkcredentialentity

It was a property with an a priori authenticated URL e.g. `data::/` instead of `https://`

2. Can you be more precise?
3. A security key is usually used by only one user. New credentials are generated each time a user uses the key to register on an application. With the use case you mentions, 2 sets of credentials will be generated by the key and associated with biometric data. There is no chance for user 2 to be logged in as user 1